# Adding Revisions to TFS Work Item using c# code

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm copying bug items from one tfs project to another. 
I'm using the copy method to create the bug in the new project, but the bug is not copied with the history details (revisions).

I need the history field to see all changes that were made and also free text that we're adding when changing States.

I tried going over each Revision item but there is no way to add the revision item to the new work item, and i can't find a way to retrieve the data I need from the Revision object.

Does anyone know how to get the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to move or copy projects (including work items) from one TFS project to another, or one server to another. I have not tried moving just work items, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on Visual Studio Gallery: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd89c5d3-4816-4f22-b04e-a397cc606be6

I have not tried this, but maybe it can be helpful.

Comment: thanks, but the project is for copying within the same tfs project.